# MySQL: Indexing Table With 10+ Million Rows

Tags: mysql, indexing, rows, partitioning

I have a table in my database with 10+M rows.
Actually I never worked with so many records and it cames across me that I need a little help on indexing / partitioning the table.

The table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `stock` (
  `ID` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `data` date NOT NULL,
  `cod_pdv` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cod_art` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `xstock` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sellout` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `backorder` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_insegna` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`,`data`),
  KEY `index_stock` (`cod_art`,`cod_pdv`,`data`),
  KEY `index_data` (`data`),
  KEY `index_trac_stock` (`cod_art`,`id_insegna`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=10120378 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
/*!50100 PARTITION BY RANGE (YEAR(data))
SUBPARTITION BY HASH (MONTH(data))
(PARTITION part0 VALUES LESS THAN (2015)
 (SUBPARTITION subpart0 ENGINE = InnoDB,
  SUBPARTITION subpart1 ENGINE = InnoDB,
  SUBPARTITION subpart2 ENGINE = InnoDB,
  SUBPARTITION subpart3 ENGINE = InnoDB,
  SUBPARTITION subpart4 ENGINE = InnoDB,
  SUBPARTITION subpart5 ENGINE = InnoDB,
  SUBPARTITION subpart6 ENGINE = InnoDB,
  SUBPARTITION subpart7 ENGINE = InnoDB,
  SUBPARTITION subpart8 ENGINE = InnoDB,
  SUBPARTITION subpart9 ENGINE = InnoDB,
  SUBPARTITION subpart10 ENGINE = InnoDB,
  SUBPARTITION subpart11 ENGINE = InnoDB,
  SUBPARTITION subpart12 ENGINE = InnoDB),
 PARTITION part1 VALUES LESS THAN (2016)
 (SUBPARTITION subpart13 ENGINE = InnoDB,
  SUBPARTITION subpart14 ENGINE = InnoDB,
  SUBPARTITION subpart15 ENGINE = InnoDB,
  SUBPARTITION subpart16 ENGINE = InnoDB,
  SUBPARTITION subpart17 ENGINE = InnoDB,
  SUBPARTITION subpart18 ENGINE = InnoDB,
  SUBPARTITION subpart19 ENGINE = InnoDB,
  SUBPARTITION subpart20 ENGINE = InnoDB,
  SUBPARTITION subpart21 ENGINE = InnoDB,
  SUBPARTITION subpart22 ENGINE = InnoDB,
  SUBPARTITION subpart23 ENGINE = InnoDB,
  SUBPARTITION subpart24 ENGINE = InnoDB,
  SUBPARTITION subpart25 ENGINE = InnoDB),
 PARTITION part2 VALUES LESS THAN (2017)
 (SUBPARTITION subpart26 ENGINE = InnoDB,
  SUBPARTITION subpart27 ENGINE = InnoDB,
  SUBPARTITION subpart28 ENGINE = InnoDB,
  SUBPARTITION subpart29 ENGINE = InnoDB,
  SUBPARTITION subpart30 ENGINE = InnoDB,
  SUBPARTITION subpart31 ENGINE = InnoDB,
  SUBPARTITION subpart32 ENGINE = InnoDB,
  SUBPARTITION subpart33 ENGINE = InnoDB,
  SUBPARTITION subpart34 ENGINE = InnoDB,
  SUBPARTITION subpart35 ENGINE = InnoDB,
  SUBPARTITION subpart36 ENGINE = InnoDB,
  SUBPARTITION subpart37 ENGINE = InnoDB,
  SUBPARTITION subpart38 ENGINE = InnoDB));
```

most of the queries run on data, cod_art, cod_pdv and id_insegna.
An example of query could be:

```
 explain 
SELECT  s.data, s.cod_art, s.giacenza, s.sellout, s.backorder
    FROM  stock AS s
    WHERE  s.cod_art IN ("103666","103672","20509","39730","5000016",
               "7004009","7004010","7004055","7004064","7004065","7004105",
               "7004133","7004161","7004163","7004178","7004213","7005932",
               "7023139","7023142","7031974","7049009","7074201","7074204",
               "7082052","7082058","7082062","7082067","7082072","7082077",
               "7084113","7084127","7088599","7091092","7091094","7094124",
               "7095505","7103663","7103678","7103681","7103684","7103687",
               "7103690","7103691","7103748","7103766","7103814","7103832",
               "7103834","7103835","7103840","7103860","7103902","7103903",
               "7103905","7103906","7103907","7104915","7104916","7104936",
               "7104957","7105357","7106936","7106937","7106938","7106943",
               "7106945","7106946","7106950","7108714","7108716","7108719",
               "7108770","7108771","7108778","7108779","7113920","7113921",
               "7113925","7113936","7114837","7115099","7115711","7115712",
               "7115713","7115714","7115715","7115716","7115717","7115719",
               "7115720","7115722","7118620","7118660","7118663","7118664",
               "7118665","7118666","7118667","7121650","7121826","7122100",
               "7122101","7122102","7122104","7122105","7122106","7122108",
               "7122112","7122113","7122115","7122119","7122120","7122123",
               "7122124","7122125","7122130","7122141","7122154","7122157",
               "7122158","7122159","7122162","7122224","7122238","7122239",
               "7122242","7122245","7122246","7122249","7122251","7122252",
               "7122256","7122257","7122262","7122266","7122272","7122273",                   "7122274","7122275","7122276","7122282","7122295","7122296",
               "7122297","7122298","7122304","7122308","7122309","7122310",                   "7122311","7122312","7122314","7122315","7122318","7122319",
               "7122326","7122327","7122370","7122371","7122372","7122374",                   "7122375","7122376","7122377","7122381","7122382","7122386",
               "7122388","7122422","7122423","7122425","7122426","7122432",                   "7122434","7122435","7122436","7122459","7122460","7122469",
               "7122470","7122474","7122475","7122479","7122480","7122483","7122484","7122486","7122489","7122496","7122498","7122504","7122505","7122680","7122682","7123119","7123141","7123151","7123152","7123368","7123900","7123945","7123949","7123950","7124025","7134016","7170052","7170055","7170058","7170062","7170067","7170072","7170077","7275297","7275298","7275299","7287682","7292630","7292631","7292644","7292645","7292659","7411238","7411627","7411628","7411629","7411630","7411631","7411632","7411633","7411678","7411679","7411933","7411944","7411955","7411961","7411995","7411996","7411997","7411998","7411999","7412007","7412008","7412009","7414118","7420171","7430455","7430722","7430724","7430728","7442570","7443160","7443178","7443179","7444126","7444220","7444225","7444733","7446020","7446060","7446080","7448499","7449594","7449645","7456561","7456607","7474229","7478302","7480817","7480834","7480836","7480865","7480868","7480869","7481360","7483186","7483199","7484430","7484431","7495863","7496040","7540619","7544450","7544452","7544459","7544460","7544490","7544491","7544842","7544843","7544854","7544855","7544856","7544930","7544931","7544934","7544935","7556801","7620180","7629100","7630592","7630598","7634033","7634035","7634694","7639626","7639628","7639629","7639658","7639661","7639664","7639669","7639670","7639694","7639709","7639894","7639895","7641894","7641895","7641896","7641898","7641933","7642087","7642089","7642098","7642099","7642141","7644215","7644219","7645021","7645022","7645023","7645027","7645040","7645047","7645058","7645059","7645073","7645074","7645076","7646558","7646741","7646742","7646743","7646745","7646746","7646764","7648910","7648912","7648913","7648925","7649244","7653052","7653056","7653325","7653750","7654141","7654500","7654505","7654507","7654514","7654518","7654542","7654554","7654556","7654560","7654565","7654566","7654567","7654568","7654569","7654587","7654588","7654734","7654736","7654745","7654750","7654770","7654777","7654779","7678400","7678419","7678420","7678421","7678426","7678470","7742625","7743642","7745754","7745762","7746585","7762401","7762409","7762417","7762423","7778939","7786921","7786999","7788416","7788473","7788512","7793723","7793731","7793779","7793780","7793783","H17103829","7108269","7108299","7135533","7135534","7135535","7135502","7135504","7135503","7135505","7135511","7135514","7135512","7135515","7135510","7135513","7123600","7123601","7123602","7123791","7123792","7123793","7123794","7123795","7123797","7123798","7123799","7654737","7250055","7286503","7250172","7250176","7250183","7250184","7250188","7208206","7286520","7451195","7017336","7017335","7495647","7495645","7495646","7451400","7451300","7451302","7451289","7451288","7451290","7451297","7451180","7451184","7444746","7444744","7444745","7451179","7451173","7451339","7101223","7101096","7101226","7101222","7101097","7101095","7101197","7101203","7101207","7101212","7113946","7113972"
                        )
      AND  s.id_insegna = '3'
      AND  s.data >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 26 WEEK)
```

EXPLAIN:

```
id  select_type table typ possible_keys                             key  key_len ref  rows  Extra
1   SIMPLE      s     ALL index_stock,index_data,index_trac_stock   NULL    NULL NULL 4917092   Using where
```

However as you can see it doesn't use any index. That could be because I don't have a combined index of with data, cod_art and id_insegna but I've read that add many indexes it may not help.

Probably I've made some mistake on creating the table? For example primary indexing the data? I'm a bit lost. I need a real huge help :v

thanks in advance to everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Plan A -- No PARTITION, just good INDEX**

`SUBPARTITION BY HASH` is useless for performance.

In fact, no form of `PARTITIONing` will speed up the `SELECT` you proposed.  And most forms will slow down the query.

The optimal index for that select should

- Start with any `= constant` parts of the `WHERE` (`id_insegna`)
- Continue with *one* 'range' field (`code_art` or `data`)

So, I would first recommend either of these.  Or both, and let the optimizer pick between them:

```
INDEX(d_insegna, code_art)
INDEX(d_insegna, data)
```

**Plan B -- better PARTITION, plus good INDEX**

Now, I will partially retract a previous statement and say that, since you have two ranges in the `WHERE`, we can try to take advantage of `PARTITION BY RANGE` to help with *one* of them.

So, I think this would be best:

```
INDEX(d_insegna, code_art)

PARTITION BY RANGE (TO_DAYS(data))
( start             VALUES LESS THAN (0),
  PARTITION p201501 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DAYS('2015-02-01')),
  PARTITION p201502 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DAYS('2015-03-01')),
  PARTITION p201503 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DAYS('2015-04-01')),
  PARTITION p201504 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DAYS('2015-05-01')),
  PARTITION p201505 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DAYS('2015-06-01')),
  PARTITION p201506 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DAYS('2015-07-01')),
  PARTITION future  VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE
)
```

With that, and the `26 WEEK` range, it will hit about 7 partitions.  Today that is all the partitions, but in the future, it will continue to be only about 7.

See [my partition blog](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint) for more details.

Do not have lots of empty partitions for the future; it is a performance hit.

**Other comments**

I do not know the distribution of `code_art`, nor whether the `IN` is typical, so I hessitate to even mention the option of `PARTITION BY RANGE(code_art)` and use the other `INDEX`.  Oops, it is not possible, since `code_art` is a `VARCHAR` and `BY RANGE` does not work with that datatype.

Caveat:  If you have other `SELECTs`, they need to be considered simultaneously with this one -- Optimization, especially when PARTITIONs are involved, cannot be done one query at a time.

Why use `VARCHAR` for what looks like numbers?

For further discussion, please include `EXPLAIN PARTITIONS SELECT ...\G`.

Comment: Why use VARCHAR for what looks like numbers? Because some cod_art may contain a x inside it.

Comment: OK.  That possibly rules out `PARTITION BY ... code_art`.